# C++: What is the name of the assignment operator which takes different data type

Tags: c++

I am in a deep confusion and cannot remember the name of the assignment operator of a class, which takes in a different data type than `const&` of the current class...

so:

```
struct Thing 
{
    Thing& operator = (const Thing& other); // This is Assignment Operator

    Thing& operator = (int xyz); // What is the name of this?

    // really not needed here, just to exemplify that this class has an int
    int memberStuff;
};
```

So, the question: what is the name of `Thing& operator = (int xyz);` being a member of `struct Thing`? Is it assignment operator or something else?

Comment: this is an assignment operator : `=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are assignments.

The only thing is that the first (taking a reference to an object of the same class) could be called a *copy* assignment operator, while the other is just a plain assignment operator.